# How to make magento/checkout/cart/ input readonly and disable UPDATE button

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I update the QTY based on `case_size` of a product. I've made an observer to do that. If the `case_size` is 144 and a customer buys two cases then QTY will automatically become 288PCS. When the customer clicks the **Edit** button then the product QTY on the add to cart page goes back to 2 case. Everything is working good, but when a customer edits the QTY see (image) then everything goes wrong of course!!

I want to remove the **UPDATE** button and make the QTY input readonly but until now no luck.

I've tried `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart.phtml` but it works on the `magento/checkout/cart/configure` page not on `magento/checkout/cart/` (see image)

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all

[image: magento/checkout/cart/]

Comment: have you used any custom magento theme?

Comment: Yes we have our own theme and I put these files in my theme's template folder. Of course no direct editing the CORE files.

Comment: pls update code in your theme's themplate file :: template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml

Comment: find  <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />

Comment: Replace :  <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" disabled="disabled" maxlength="12" />

Comment: and comment update button code

Answer (score 0):

To finalize the question [Mr.Abdul](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/31184/abdul) has answered me and after change everything is working as expected.

So the problem is solved. Thank you Mr. Abdul and everyone else.